# angularjs: match text with array of values

Tags: javascript

```js
exports.searchcomments = function (req, res) {
    var searchText = !!req.params && req.params.searchtext || null;
    var matchedComments = [];
    ReferenceValue.find({ domaincode: 'DEPOSITCMNTS' })
        .lean()
        .exec(function (error, refValueDocs) {
            if (!!error) {
                billingUtils.doErrorResponse({
                    error: 'ERRORS.REFUNDABLEAMOUNT'
                }, req, res, error);
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < refValueDocs.length; i++) {
                    refValueDocs[i].valuedescription = new RegExp('^' + searchText, 'i')
                }
            }
        })
};
```

while exec the query, i will get refValueDocs which is array. I want to check `refValueDocs[i].valuedescription` matches with `searchText`. And also matched ones are to be pushed into an `matchedComments` array. How do I check the `searchText` matches with `refValueDocs[i].valuedescription`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter values in an array and it will return new array containing filtered objects.

```js
exports.searchcomments = function (req, res) {
    var searchText = !!req.params && req.params.searchtext || null;
    var matchedComments = [];
    ReferenceValue.find({ domaincode: 'DEPOSITCMNTS' })
        .lean()
        .exec(function (error, refValueDocs) {
            if (!!error) {
                billingUtils.doErrorResponse({
                    error: 'ERRORS.REFUNDABLEAMOUNT'
                }, req, res, error);
            } else {
                matchedComments = refValueDocs.filter(function(doc){
                    var regex = new RegExp('^' + searchText, 'i');
                    return doc.valuedescription.match(regex);
                });
            }
        })
};
```